# What does the expression "I'm deal" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I cannot understand this phrase. The context where I came across it is as follows:

> - Do you realize what you've done? Beast Boy is with a child?
> - No, it's just an egg, I'm not with a child. Am I?
> - That's how eggs work, boy! That egg is gonna become a chicken.
>   [...]
> - **I'm deal**, I always wanted to be a daddy.

From the cartoon "Teen Titans Go" (episode *Chicken in the Cradle*).

Comment: It's a misunderstanding, unfortunately.  Beast Boy has a slight Hispanic accent and though I can hear how you got "I'm deal." from it, he is actually saying, "I'll deal."  This is a shortened version of "I'll deal with it," meaning that he will cope with or handle the stress of being a father.  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSBYYfeZrGY&t=70s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSBYYfeZrGY&t=70s)

Comment: On reflection, it's less the slight accent (that isn't particularly apparent in this clip anyway) but rather the character's manor of speaking that caused the issue.  He is portrayed as a hip young man, and he often speaks with a youthful, urban cadence.  They're trying to make him sound cool and street wise.

Comment: The character in question likes to use the informal contraction "Imma" = "I'm gonna" = "I'm going to". I wonder (but can't think how to find out) if "I'm deal" was a misspoken "Imma deal".

Answer (score 1):

It's slang. Perhaps "fake" slang created to give the character a distinctive way of talking. We can probably guess from the context and the usual meanings of "deal".

Saying "I can deal with something" means you are able to cope with the situation. So in slang "I can deal with that. I always wanted to be a daddy" has been transformed to "I'm deal..."

The writers of things like Teen Titans know that they can never keep up with real teen slang, so they do just invent stuff that sounds plausible.

Comment: I always say if I down  vote. I down voted here. You say it is slang without any real evidence. To say it is fake slang, makes your guess even less reliable.  Usually on this site, in my experience, the OP has mis-heard the word and my  guess would be that that is what happened here.

Comment: I have kids.  I have watched this episode, and that's what he says.  The reason I say "fake slang" is that I can't find any actual use of this outside that episode.  So probably something dreamt up the writers to make the character sound "deal".

Comment: For what it's worth, the character in question generally uses slang and often comes off as silly so it's certainly in keeping with his character to use something that sounds like slang but is actually made up. The full line is "Bro, sis, dudes chill, I'm deal".

Answer (score -2):

It's a meme:

[image]

And it means I'm deal[ing with something]

I'm OK With This - I'm deal with this.

[know your meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1874031-im-ok-with-this)

Answer (score -3):

Alas! I don't know these Teen Titans.

Deal is an unusual name. Perhaps s/he is saying,

**"I'm Dale"**

*Dale* can be either a boy's or a girl's name, especially in Scandinavia.

Sometimes people use their initials. As a boy I used to enjoy an animation called Top Cats, in which the leader of the gang was known as T.C. Perhaps s/he is saying,

**"I'm D.L."**

Or perhaps s/he has a head cold which makes their N's sound like D's. In which case s/he is saying,

**"I'm Neil, I always wanted to be a nanny".**

Comment: I'm pretty sure the character who says this is "Beast Boy" or "Beastie" to his friends.  Not Dale or Neil. And I think the context is that Beast Boy (who can transform into any animal) has laid an egg while in the form of a chicken...  Shakespeare it aint.

Comment: Sadly Shakespeare's Teen Titania was left unfinished. Does "I'm Dale" make sense now that we know he's laid an egg? Or does it - as I suspect - simply deepen the mystery?

Comment: I always say if I down vote. I down voted here because you are just guessing. We need more information from the OP before we can give a reliable answer.

Comment: I posted my suggestions hoping the OP might not have considered them and that he/she might pounce on one and say, "That's IT. He IS called Dale!" or "Yeah: he IS Scandinavian." I'm not guessing. I'm using my ears and my experience (all three of which I use professionally!) to weigh the possibilities and make suggestions. Until someone who worked on the cartoon shows up I'm afraid suggestions are all we've got.

Comment: Watched the clip. Definitely not saying a name and the transcript is correct.